# WPF DataGridTextColumn adding PreviewMouseDown Event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to using a keyboard in my WPF Desktop Project.Normally I'm using a datagrid and all values come from my database.My aim is when I click a cell of datagrid then must be open my custom keyboard.For this reason I want to use previewmousedown event in my datagridtextcolumn.How can I achieve that?Is anyone help me?

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagridusers" 
                                
          materialDesign:ColorZoneAssist.Background="Wheat"  
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="400" Margin="20 80 20 20" 
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
          VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
          Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGrid}" 
          FontSize="15" 
          materialDesign:ScrollViewerAssist.SupportHorizontalScroll="True" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="USER ID" 
                                           Binding="{Binding Id}"    
                                           IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns >
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You can format your `xaml` content for example using backticks like so ```

Comment: Hi !I don't understand what do you mean?Here is my Problem.My all datagrid pieces occurs datagridtextcolumn.I have customized all of.When I wannt to use Keyboard here I have to use a click event.But I don't know how can I use in a DatagridTextColumn this events like previewmousedown or soo.Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi Mustafa, I meant the formatting of the `XAML` that you pasted can be improved, so that readers perhaps might perhaps find your Question not as easily readable as it could be.

Comment: As for the comment-question _"how can I use in a DatagridTextColumn this events like previewmousedown or soo.Can you help me please?"_ I'll posted an answer, hope that it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your question

> how can I use in a DatagridTextColumn this events like previewmousedown or so?

This is a copied and pasted example from a real-world project:
*View xaml:*

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2"
              x:Name="dataGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}"
              PreviewMouseDown="DataGrid_PreviewMouseDown">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemName}"
                                Header="{Binding Source={x:Static local:AppLocalization.NameGiven}}" 
                                Width="110*" MinWidth="110"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

*code-behind.cs:*

```
        private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //  open your custom keyboard here
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. .You've really helped me.Bu I've used another way to customize my datagrid column.Its working.

Comment: I can't share all off code but I can explain a bit.  I'm using here datagridtemplatecolumn and datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate.And in a celltemplate I have used a textbox and customized it.